# Custom taxonomies Dropdown without a Submit Button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I Developing one project and I stuck in small thing which is very small for PHP Expert :D Which i'm not

I'm Trying to make Dropdown list of Custom taxonomies which work on select go to that Custom taxonomies page.

But After lot of search I found Solution But not doing action to go to the selected Custom taxonomies

First I found

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'taxonomy=my_custom_taxonomy' ); ?>
```

Second I found

```
function fjarrett_custom_taxonomy_dropdown( $taxonomy ) {
$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );
if ( $terms ) {
    printf( '<select name="%s" class="postform">', esc_attr( $taxonomy ) );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        printf( '<option value="%s">%s</option>', esc_attr( $term->slug ), esc_html( $term->name ) );
    }
    print( '</select>' );
}
}
```

Which I can use when I insert in any page code billow

```
<?php fjarrett_custom_taxonomy_dropdown( 'my_custom_taxonomy' ); ?>
```

> Credit
>   https://frankiejarrett.com/2011/09/create-a-dropdown-of-custom-taxonomies-in-wordpress-the-easy-way/

BUT I DON'T KNOW NOW HOW I GONNA MAKE IT WORKING

Hope you can help me to find solution that from above any one solution can I able to make select and go thing.

---

Thanks in advance

### POSSIBLE ANSWER - 1

I Found Possible Answer

```
<form id="category-select" class="category-select" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" method="get">

    <?php
    $args = array(
        'show_option_none' => __( 'Select category' ),
        'show_count'       => 1,
        'orderby'          => 'name',
        'name'             => 'cat',
        'echo'             => 0,
        'taxonomy'         => 'MyCustomTaxonomys',
        'value_field'      => 'slug'
    );
    ?>

    <?php $select  = wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?>
    <?php $replace = "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>"; ?>
    <?php $select  = preg_replace( '#<select([^>]*)>#', $replace, $select ); ?>

    <?php echo $select; ?>

    <noscript>
        <input type="submit" value="View" />
    </noscript>

</form>
```

It Give me URL

> www.website.com/?cat=xxx  where xxx is my custom taxonomy

But I Want URL

> www.website.com/cat/xxx  where xxx is my custom taxonomy

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You

could use something like this :

```
<?php
        function fjarrett_custom_taxonomy_dropdown( $taxonomy ) {
        $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );
        if ( $terms ) {
        printf( '<select name="%s" class="postform">', esc_attr( $taxonomy ) );
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            printf( '<option value="%s" data-location="%s">%s</option>', esc_attr( $term->slug ), get_term_link(term_id), esc_html( $term->name ) );
        }
    print( '</select>' );
}
}
?>
```

Then use your javascript code to redirect depending on the value of the attribute `data-location`

Comment: Thanks for the answer bu it has 2 error :                                            
                             Notice:  Use of undefined constant term_id - assumed 'term_id' in  AND

Catchable fatal error:  Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in

Comment: Hi There I found one Possible answer (updated in question) but  I not get url as I want it ... Will you help me with it?

Comment: Thanks for the efforts I found Alternate answer... But If you can figure out the previous posted possible answer then it firm solution new kind of solution i think.... Again  Thanks a lot for your efforts and answer

Comment: $term->term_id instead of term_id

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way like you say with PHP with wordpres:

```
<?php function click_taxonomy_dropdown($taxonomy, $title) { ?>
  <select name="<?php echo $taxonomy;?>" id="<?php echo $taxonomy;?>">
  <option value="-1"><?php echo $title;?></option>
  <?php
  $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
  foreach ($terms as $term) {
      $link = get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy );

      if($term->parent == 0){
    printf( '<option class="level-1" value="'.$link.'">%s</option>', $term->name );
  }
  }
  echo '</select>';
  ?>
<?php } ?>
```

And then with JS:

```
var dropdown1=document.getElementById("yourtaxonomy");
    function onCatChange1(){
      if(dropdown1.options[dropdown1.selectedIndex].value>"")
        location.href=dropdown1.options[dropdown1.selectedIndex].value
    }
```

The JS just get the ID of your select and then go to value when options are selected

Comment: Thank you for the answer, But It weird mix of error and pulling different data then  need of .... Above all PHP code I show you it give me result in ID and also Custom taxonomy but not as any link ... so i want to use that Custom taxonomy as link and go to that Custom taxonomy page

Comment: Hi There I found one Possible answer (updated in question) but  I not get url as I want it ... Will you help me with it?

Comment: Thanks for the efforts I found Alternate answer... But If you can figure out the previous posted possible answer then it firm solution new kind of solution i think.... Again  Thanks a lot for your efforts and answer

Comment: This work perfectly on my end...Don't understand your answer :p

Answer (score 0):

AT End I Found One Alternate Working Solution Writing here so it will help someone needful

```
<?php

  $categories = get_categories('taxonomy=xxxx');

  $select = "<select name='' id='cat' class='postform'>n";
  $select.= "<option value='-1'>Select category</option>n";

 foreach($categories as $category){
if($category->count > 0){
    $select.= "<option value='".$category->slug."'>".$category->name."
</option>";
  }
  }

  $select.= "</select>";

  echo $select;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");

    function onCatChange() {
        if (dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value != -1) {
            location.href = "<?php echo home_url();?>/yyyy/" + dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value + "/";
        }
    }
    dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
    -->
</script>
```

JUST SET Proper XXXX and YYYY Value and solve.

> Credit: John B. Hartley
>   http://www.johnbhartley.com/2012/custom-taxonomy-category-dropdown/

Again Thank you all for your efforts